# Intersection of sets and creating disjoint sets in numba

Tags: python, set, numba

In the following problem I have a list called `a` which contains `N` sets of different length. With `set.intersection(*a)` I get the intersection of all sets within `a`. Unfortunately this does not work in numba, which is my first problem. My second problem is, that I would like to subtract from all sets in `a` the intersection set. Without numba the following code should work

```
new_a = [{}]*N
intersectionset = set.intersection(*a)
for x in range(N):
    new_a[x] = a[x]-intersectionset


Example: a=[{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3},{1,2}]
--->intersectionsset = {1,2}
--->new_a =[{3,4},{3},{}]
```

How could I efficiently implement this within numba? Thanks! Btw. would this be the most efficient algorithm outside of numba?

Edit: I'm also very interested if this is the fastest implementation of my code, when numba is not used.

Comment: What is `set_wp` ? Can you also please post the complete error stack trace along with the numba code you have written ?

Comment: If `set.intersection(*a)` doesn't work, what about `a[0].intersection(*a[1:])`?

Comment: Also, `new_a = [{}]*N` doesn't do what you think it does. It makes a list of N references to a single dict. You then replace all those references with references to new sets in the subsequent loop.

Comment: Also, the only type Numba can `*`-unpack is tuples, and calling `tuple` on a list isn't supported. If `a` is a list, you'll have to either convert it to a tuple outside Numba or call `intersection` one set at a time.

Comment: @MohammedKashif: Sorry that was a mistake, which I've corrected. It should be clear now.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica: a[0].intersection(*a[1:]) also does not work because auf `*`-unpack I guess.

Comment: I think creating a tuple is not feasible then, because a will be changed iteratively within a numba loop.

Comment: How large is N in your real data?  Is each of the N sets typically large (thousands of elements, or small?  How large is `intersectionset` in your real data?  What running time do you get now (without Numba), and what running time would you find acceptable?

Comment: N is about 100-1000. The intersectionset in each iteration is rather small. Maybe 10 at most